# Degree two subschemes of projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y^r\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ be a subscheme that has the same Hilbert polynomial of an $r$-dimensional irreducible quadric hypersurface $Q^r\subset\mathbb{P}^{r+1}$.
If $\mathcal{L}$ denote the set of linear subspaces $L\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ which contain $Y^r$ (as subscheme), is it true that $\bigcap \mathcal{L}$ is a linear space of dimension $r+1$?

This is a slight generalization of exercise 7.8 of Hartshorne`s book "Algebraic Geometry" (chapter I, pag. 55).

Thank you.

Comment: Well, this is in general not true if $Y$ is reducible. Take as $Y$ the union of two skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$: then $\dim Y=1$ but there is a unique linear space containing it, namely $\mathbb{P}^3$ itself. In fact, Hartshorne's exercise is about *varieties* (i.e. in his terminology irreducible algebraic sets), not schemes. 

Comment: Thank you. I allowed myself to edit my question as appropriate.